# CSS element>element selector in style attibute

Tags: html, css

Can this code be replicated using the style attribute?

```
<style>
#red-paragraphs > p {
color:red;
}
</style>

<div id="red-paragraphs">
<p>red paragraph</p>
<p>another red paragraph</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>not red paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Somehow like this:

```
<div style="????????">
<p>red paragraph</p>
<p>another red paragraph</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>not red paragraph</p>
</div>
```

I would only be using the style once, and I would like to change the file where the change is being done.

Comment: simply `color:red` since color is inherited

Comment: @TemaniAfif the point isn't the actual color, but rather the idea of inheriting the style - sry I made it confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a reference to [HTML Style Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style#:%7E:text=The%20style%20property%20is%20used,the%20element%27s%20inline%20style%20attribute.)

```html
<div style="color: red;opacity: 0.5;">
<p>red paragraph</p>
<p>another red paragraph</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>not red paragraph</p>
</div>
```

inline styling does not support child selecting inheritance since that's what CSS made for. you can only do this:

```html
<div>
  <p style="color: red;opacity: 0.5;">red paragraph</p>
  <p style="color: red;opacity: 0.5;">another red paragraph</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>not red paragraph</p>
</div>
```